# How to combine 3 variables. Pretty simple

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a problem that asks me to combine three numeric variables, for example, **a = 1 , b = 2 , c = 3**. We're supposed to make d = ' 1|2|3 '.  I've done some scripting in BASH where **"|"** refers to piping. How would you accomplish this in Python, and what does **"|"** mean?

Comment: So the input is three independent integers and the output is a string like `"1|2|3"`?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Could you show us what you have tried and further explain what you are trying to do here?

Comment: `'|'.join(map(str,[a,b,c]))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vertical bar is merely a character.  Treat this the same way you would a comma or a dash.  Convert each integer to string, and concatenate them with the bar in between.  This is merely an exercise in string manipulation; nothing particularly deep or tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a list of all the variables, and join them using the pipe symbol.

```
"|".join(map(str, [a, b, c]))
```

Comment: OP wants '1|2|3' not 'a|b|c'

Comment: @bulbus Thanks. Fixed it.

Comment: @bulbus Fixed that too :)

Comment: Or `"|".join([str(x) for x in [a, b, c]])`

Comment: @bulbus Nah, still on `map` bus. I could have used `str` method directly however, as you did in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are expected to do or mean by "combining". In Python you can combine variables into tuples so that you can have a "compound" or combined variable that you can use for lookup tables, etc.

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
combined = (a,b,c)
```

now you can do things like `x = {combined: "value"}`

Answer (score 0):

The solution hspandher is on the right track, but would work primarily for one set of three numeric variables. It might be more useful to create a function like this:

```
def numberCombiner(a, b, c):
    return str(a)+"|"+str(b)+"|"+str(c)
numberCombiner(1,2,3)
```

Which would take in three numeric values and output the string you want. Then you can call/invoke the numberCombiner function on different values, like:

```
numberCombiner(2,3,4)
```

which would return

```
>>> '2|3|4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using format:

```
>>> a=1
>>> b=2
>>> c=3
>>> "{}|{}|{}".format(a,b,c)
'1|2|3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a generator expression to convert your integer variables into strings, and join them with the vertical line symbol.

```
"|".join(str(v) for v in [a, b, c])
```

[More about generator expression.](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions)

[More about string joining.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

Thanks to juanpa.arrivillaga for pointing out the generator expression syntax where the generator is used right away by an enclosing function. See comments for more information.

Comment: That is not a list comprehension, that is a generator expression.

Comment: Could you give a link or briefly explain? According to the official documentation this seems like a list comprehension: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Yes, [here is a link to the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions). Note, a list comprehension is enclosed in square-brackets, like a list-literal, e.g. `[str(v) for v in [a, b, c]`, the equivalent generator expression is `(str(v) for v in [a, b, c])`, note the round-brackets. Also, if a generator expression is the only argument in a functional call, the round-parenthesis can be omitted